# Boost.DLL cannot find symbols in executable using statically linked library

Tags: c++, boost, static-libraries, debug-symbols

I am currently writing a small test application to explore statically linking libraries and accessing their symbols at runtime with Boost.DLL. I am compiling a very simple static library and link it with a very simple application, using MinGW-w64, and am doing this with a Makefile and `mingw32-make`.

`A.cpp` defines a class `A` that stores and modifies a reference to an `int`. The library's only module `B.cpp` defines a subclass of `A` called `B`, as well as a factory method. The main module defines a class `C` which stores a reference to an instance of `A`, and attempts to access the symbols defined in `B.cpp` to store an instance of `B` in `C`. When I attempt to run the application, the output file is successfully loaded but the program fails to locate the statically linked symbols.

**A.hpp**:

```
#pragma once

#ifndef A_HPP_
#define A_HPP_

#include <memory>
#include <boost/dll/config.hpp>
#include <boost/dll.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class A {
protected:
    int *_p;
public:
    A(int *p = NULL);
    virtual ~A() = default;
    
    void setp(int *p);
    int deref();

    virtual void add();
};

#endif
```

**B.cpp**:

```
#include "A.hpp"

class B : public A {
public:
    B();
    ~B();

    void add();
};

const size_t B_SIZE = sizeof(B);
void B_get(void *addr) {
    B *tmp = new B();
    memcpy(addr, tmp, B_SIZE);
    delete tmp;
}

B::B() {}
B::~B() {}

void B::add() {
    if (_p != NULL)
        *_p = *_p + 100;
    std::cout << "B: _p is now " << *_p << std::endl;
}
```

**main.cpp**:

```
#include "A.hpp"

class C {
public:
    std::shared_ptr<A> a;

    C(std::shared_ptr<A> aparam, int *x) : a(aparam) { a->setp(x); }
    int deref() { return a->deref(); }
};

int main() {
    std::string loc = boost::dll::program_location().string();

    std::cout << "loading file '" << loc << "'" << std::endl;
    boost::dll::shared_library lib(loc);
    
    std::cout << "getting symbol 'B_SIZE'" << std::endl;
    size_t B_SIZE = lib.get<size_t>("B_SIZE");

    std::cout << "getting symbol 'B_get(void*)'" << std::endl;
    boost::function<void(void*)> B_get = lib.get<void(void*)>("B_get");
    
    std::cout << "getting instance of B" << std::endl;
    void *b = new char[B_SIZE];
    B_get(b);
    
    //assign x and C
    int x = 5;
    C c(std::shared_ptr<A>((A*)b), &x);

    std::cout << "x: " << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "c.a->deref(): " << c.a->deref() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "executing c.a->add()" << std::endl;
    c.a->add();

    std::cout << "x: " << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "c.a->deref(): " << c.a->deref() << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Makefile**:

```
#build executable
out:
    g++ -Wall -c -IC:/Unix/boost_1_78_0/ B.cpp -o B.o
    ar -rcs -o libB.a B.o
    g++ -Wall -IC:/Unix/boost_1_78_0/ -LC:/Unix/boost_1_78_0/stage/lib -L. main.cpp A.cpp -llibboost_filesystem-mgw8-mt-x64-1_78 -llibboost_system-mgw8-mt-x64-1_78 -Wl,-Bstatic -lB -o out

#build and run executable
run: out
    ./out
```

Output:

```
C:\Unix\VSC\Static_Test>mingw32-make run
g++ -Wall -c -IC:/Unix/boost_1_78_0/ B.cpp -o B.o
ar -rcs -o libB.a B.o
g++ -Wall -IC:/Unix/boost_1_78_0/ -LC:/Unix/boost_1_78_0/stage/lib -L. main.cpp A.cpp -llibboost_filesystem-mgw8-mt-x64-1_78 -llibboost_system-mgw8-mt-x64-1_78 -Wl,-Bstatic -lB -o out
./out
loading file 'C:\Unix\VSC\Static_Test\out.exe'
getting symbol 'B_SIZE'
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::wrapexcept<boost::system::system_error>'
  what():  boost::dll::shared_library::get() failed: The specified procedure could not be found [system:127]
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:9: run] Error 3
```

I have used `nm` to inspect `out.exe` and `libB.a`, and all relevant symbols for `A`, `B`, and `C` are defined, but the symbols for `B` are missing from `out.exe`.

I have also attempted to compile the executable with combinations of the flags `-g` and `-O0`, with no success.

As I understand it, a header for `B.cpp` included in `main.cpp` *shouldn't* be necessary to locate the symbols, nor are any symbol exporting qualifiers like `extern "C"` or `__declspec(dllexport)` (though I have tried all of those things as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

boost::DLL works only with *exported* symbols.  Your symbols are not exported. "Exporting" symbols is something that is outside the scope of the C++ language. It needs to be done with __declspec(dllexport) or similar.

Statically linked symbols are not accessible at runtime. The linker discards them.

---

The error says "B_SIZE" not found. B_SIZE is defined in B.cpp as

```
const size_t B_SIZE = sizeof(B);
```

This symbol is never exported. It is linked statically to your .exe and it's definition will then be discarded.

You probably could change this to

```
const size_t __declspec(dllexport) B_SIZE = sizeof(B);
```

to force it to be exported (although exporting a variable as opposed to a function comes with it's own problems). Then, in theory, the compiler should tag it as "export this" and the lib command `ar` should honor this information as it builds the static lib "B.o"

Finally, when the implicit linker call in your `g++ -Wall ... exe -lB` command get's executed, the linker should bind the static lib "B.o" to your exe, find the "please export me" flag and copy the symbol information for `B_SIZE` to the .exe.

Only if you *export* a symbol, the info will be written to the .dll. Then other programs will be able to look it up.

---

One more thing, hidden in the boost DLL tutorial. Under Windows, `__declspec(dllexport)` will export the symbols even for a .EXE file. So if you statically link your B.o to the .EXE, the windows tools *will* honor the `dllexport` tag and export the symbol. That's true for Microsoft and similar linkers.

The small note in the tutorial regarding linux says, you have to pass `-rdynamic` to the linux linker. I am guessing here, but since exporting symbols from a .EXE is unusual (standard is .DLL), the linux tools might ignore all `dllexport` tags and explicitly hide exported symbols from the runtime - unless you explicitly tell them to include them, which is what `-rdynamic` could be for.

---

BTW, the way this is usually done is like this:

```
#if defined(MYLIB_EXPORTS)
#define MYLIB_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else if defined(MYLIB_IMPORTS)
#define MYLIB_API __declspec(dllimport)
#else
#define MYLIB_API /* */
#endif

void MYLIB_API B_get(void*);
```

Comment: Adding the ``__declspec(dllexport)`` does not fix the problem. As shown on the [tutorial for Boost.DLL](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/boost_dll/tutorial.html), statically linked libraries can indeed be used; however, that ``__declspec`` is used, as you said (the ``BOOST_DLL_ALIAS`` macro expands as that, but I believe they do so only to provide an alias), but even using that still does not solve the problem. I've even done exactly as the tutorial has, creating ``B.hpp`` and including that header in the ``main.cpp`` module (even though I'd like to avoid that), with no success.

Comment: I've modified my answer a bit. Also please see the "note" for Linux in the tutorial regarding -rdynamic.  Since you are using mingw/c++, this note will probably apply to your example as well, because mingw is essentially a linux tool on Windows.